# saturation formula

Tags: calculus, chemistry

I have a differential equation

$$\frac{dB}{dt}=\epsilon I-\delta B.$$
I want to understand why $B \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}.$

$B$ is the concentration of a virus in the environment, $\epsilon$ is the rate at which infectious individuals $I$ shed virus onto the environment and $\delta$ is the rate at which virus is removed from the environment by sanitation.

Why is it that saturation of virus concentration is $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$?

Comment: At the critical point $dB/dt=0$, it is trivial to observe that $B=\epsilon I/\delta$. If $I\leq 1$ and this point is a global maximum (i.e. second derivative test), then the statement $B\leq\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$ holds for all $t$. Is there any more information? Dynamics on $I$ would help.

Comment: @UNOwen, thanks a lot. Your comment was really helpful, I get it now.